# How to show/Hide Data in dropDownList field depending on other list boolean field (lookup value)

Tags: list, sharepoint-2013, lookup

i am working with sharepoint 2013...
I have two lists;

1°/ `Cars{brand,color,price}`
2°/ `Colors{designation,availability`}.

I made the field 'color' (cars list's field) as a lookup field to display colors from colors list.
While filling data in cars list, in the field color, i want to just find colors with availibility "yes" in the availability field of colors list.
How can i get this please?

Can anyone help me please?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new view on your cars list. Then filter so it only shows items where the availbility = yes

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the second list has {colour, designation,availability}.
There are two solutions:
The first solution is in second list, you add a calculated field that = if Availability=true:[field with color]:"". That will filter out all non-available colors. Yet, you should have a problem when changing from available to not available - i.e you 'll loose information on the previous records.

The second solution needs jquery and ajax. Basically, on document load, you check every option if it's available - if it's not, delete it.The only drawback is that you need to have somewhere jquery.js  I'm in the house but if you want it, I could write the code tomorrow.
The code is:

```
$(window).ready(function() { 
$("#PutHereTHeIDOfthedropodown > option").each(
function(index) {
                if (window.console) console.log("inside" + index+"," + $(this).val()); //39, 51 κλπ
                // $(this).hide();// with this, we hide the selection!!
                var mythis = $(this);
                $.ajax( {
                    url:"http://YourWebSite/sites/DNY/_api/Lists(guid'b5910edd-8a39-4d45-GUID-Of-The-List')/items(" + mythis.val()+")?$select=Active",
                    type:"GET",
                     headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    },
                  success: function(data){ console.log("ajax call SUCCESS");  
                                       console.log("item:"+mythis.val());
                                            console.log("Data:" + data);
                                            console.log("Active: " + data.d.Active);
                                        if (!data.d.Active) {
                                            console.log("hiding: " + mythis.val() + "["+ "]");
                                            mythis.hide();
                        }//if
                }//success
                    ,
                    error: function(error){
                                           console.log(" =============================================>>Error:" + mythis.val());
                                           console.log (JSON.stringify(error));
                                           console.log(" Error:" + mythis.val());
                                           console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                            }//error
                    });//ajax
                });//each
            });//ready
```

Comment: that would be great if you write some code !! thank you

Comment: I've done it. I'm newbie to javascript/jquery, but I thing the code is straightforward and it only needs to change the paramaters. First, try the line "http://YourWebSite/sites/DNY/_api/Lists(guid'b5910edd-8a39-4d45-GUID-Of-The-List')/items(" + mythis.val()+")?$select=Active" . Active is the field which tells me if it's active or not (Yes/No) field type.